# Probability depending on draw order

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am trying to figure if drawing order has an influence on probability.

There are 100 balls in a box, 10 of them are red, 90 of them are black.
100 different person are taking turn to draw a ball.

Is there a prefered position to take to draw a red ball (before knowing any of the draws) or is the probability constant (0.1) ?

First person has 10 out of 100 = 0.1 chance of drawing a red ball.
My intuition is that since its 0.1 for the first one, in 9 cases out of ten, the second drawer will have 10 out of 99, and in the other 9 out of 99, which would translate in 0.9*(10/99) + 0.1*(9/99) = 0.1

Does this remain constant over the course of the drawing ?
How can i generalise this formula with P(drawing a red ball), N the sample size (here 100)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun thank you for your input, I wanted to keep it short to be more easily readable but added more info about what I did so far

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, by counting over all of the combinations of balls possible, the probability of the $j^{th}$ ball being red is

$$\frac{\binom{99}{9}}{\binom{100}{10}}$$

because $\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}$, this equals $0.1$.

More technically, the probability of the $j^{th}$ ball being red can be determined by looking at all the previous cases.

Assume $k$ red balls have already been drawn.

$$\frac{(100-j)!}{100!}\frac{10!}{(9-k)!}\frac{90!}{(90-j+k)!}\binom{j-1}{k}$$

Collecting the straight factorials together gives

$$\frac1{\binom{100}{10}}\frac{(100-j)!}{(9-k)!(90-j+k)!}\binom{j-1}{k}$$

and summing over $k$

$$\frac1{\binom{100}{10}}\sum_{k=0}^j\frac{(100-j)!}{(9-k)!(90-j+k)!}\binom{j-1}{k}$$

$$\frac1{\binom{100}{10}}\sum_{k=0}^j\binom{100-j}{9-k}\binom{j-1}{k}$$

and applying [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) gives the result.